# Trying to do over 1000000 damage in a sword but a comma is in the way

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:100000000,Operation:2,UUIDLeast:669718,UUIDMost:872863}],HideFlags:0}
```

That command is giving the output of:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "," at "unt:100000000>>,<<Operation:"
```

What is going on?

Bedrock Edition

Comment: I have no clue about all this, but isn't the maximum 2048, according to this [website](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Attribute) (search for `generic.attackDamage`)?

Comment: This looks like JSON-like data. What happens if you enclosed each value with " (parentheses)? E.g. Amount:"1000000"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the bedrock edition doesn't support this .